# scala- Read file from S3 bucket

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

I want to read a specific file from S3 bucket. In my S3 bucket I will be having so many objects(directories and Sub directories). I want traverse through all the objects and have to read only that file.

I am trying below code:

```
val s3Client: AmazonS3Client = getS3Client()
    try {
      log.info("Listing objects from S3")
      var counter = 0

      val listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
        .withBucketName(bucketName)
        .withMaxKeys(2)
        .withPrefix("Test/"+"Client_cd" + "/"+"DM1"+"/")
        .withMarker("Test/"+"Client_cd" + "/"+"DM1"+"/")
      var objectListing: ObjectListing = null
      do {
        objectListing = s3Client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest)
        import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
        for (objectSummary <- objectListing.getObjectSummaries) {
          println( objectSummary.getKey + "\t" + StringUtils.fromDate(objectSummary.getLastModified))

        }
          listObjectsRequest.setMarker(objectListing.getNextMarker())
        }
        while (objectListing.isTruncated())

    }
    catch {
      case e: Exception => {
        log.error("Failed listing files. ", e)
        throw e
      }
    }
```

In this path I have to read only .gz files from latest month folders. File Path:

```
"Mybucket/Test/Client_cd/Dm1/20181010_xxxxx/*.gz"
```

Here, I have to pass Client_cd as parameter for particular client.

How to filter the objects and to get particular files?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a prefix of "Test/Client_cd/Dm1/20181010_" and not supplying  a marker on the initial list objects request? You'll have to filter the results locally to get just the *.gz files (unless they're all *.gz files).

Comment: Hi,If you see in my picture i am having multiple client_cd folders and i have to pass as a parameter as client_cd (to filter) and i have to find the latest two months folders data under DM1.

Comment: There's no magic available here. You could read the prefix Test/Client_cd/Dm1/201812, then 201811, etc. down to 201801 until you have found two months that actually have data.

Comment: If  in that case i can read all the data from dm1. In dm1 folder i will be having 12 months data. I want only latest 2 months data and every month these data generated by system automatically.

Comment: If there are not too many files under Dm1 then you might want to just list them all, sort by descending date, and find the most recent two months. If there are a lot of files but they all have a common YYYY prefix, then you can start at December and work backwards (YYYY12 then YYYY11 etc.).

Comment: The core logic is that i want to compare the latest two months sets of data from s3 bucket. I want to find the difference between these two data sets (Latest Month and Previous month). I don't want to read all the data from dm1.

Comment: I have added that logic in my code through getlastmodfied. I am not getting how to take only two latest file? kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EMR or your S3 configs are setup correctly, you can also use the `sc.textFile("s3://bucket/Test/Client_cd/Dm1/20181010_xxxxx/*.gz")`

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the details. I am able to access the files from S3 bucket. How can i read the data recursively? In Dm1 folder i will be having months data folders(assume 12 months)  and under these folders  i am having *.gz files. I want to consider only latest two months data like (20181013,20180911..etc) and we have to perform automation and no physical path .

Comment: standard expressions to read file from multiple paths should work. think of s3:// as a file read protocol and rest as file paths. u can play with it just like u play with ls on local file system.

Comment: @ Dragonborn, Thanks for your response. Is it possible through coding?